# Install 64bit app on (32bit userland/64bit kernel) debian

Tags: apt

I am trying to install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, I am trying to install the 64bit version, as 32bit is no-longer available.

I can not get it to install without removing binutils:i386.
**How can I install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` on this mostly 32bit system?**

What I have tried:

```
#> sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree:amd64
[sudo] password for richard:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pepperflashplugin-nonfree:amd64 : Depends: binutils:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I try to add binutils (64bit version)

```
#> sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree:amd64 binutils:amd64;
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dblatex docbook-to-man docbook-utils eclipse-cdt-jni highlight highlight-common intltool
  kernel-common libsgmls-perl linux-kbuild-3.16 sgmlspl texlive texlive-bibtex-extra
  texlive-math-extra xmlto
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libnspr4:amd64 libnss3:amd64
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc:amd64 chromium:amd64 ttf-mscorefonts-installer:amd64 ttf-dejavu:amd64
  ttf-xfree86-nonfree:amd64 hal:amd64
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  binutils build-essential debhelper dpkg-dev eclipse-cdt equivs g++ g++-4.9 gcc gcc-4.8
  gcc-4.9 gnome-common gtk-doc-tools hardening-includes kernel-package libtool lintian
  linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-686-pae linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
  linux-headers-686-pae linux-headers-amd64 network-manager-pptp pptp-linux
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils:amd64 libnspr4:amd64 libnss3:amd64 pepperflashplugin-nonfree:amd64
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 24 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,806 kB of archives.
After this operation, 117 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

However this tells be that it will remove the 32bit version.
If I tell it to install both, it tells be there is a conflict.

```
#> sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree:amd64 binutils:amd64 binutils:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
binutils is already the newest version.
binutils set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 binutils:amd64 : Conflicts: binutils but 2.25-5 is to be installed
 binutils : Conflicts: binutils:amd64 but 2.25-5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

I am running Debian Jessie 32bit, except kernel and virtual box are 64-bit (virtual box has to match kernel).

```
#> uname -a
Linux richard-laptop 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

#> dpkg-query -l "virtualbox*" base-files
||/ Name            Version                    Architecture  Description 
ii  virtualbox-5.1  5.1.14-112924~Debian~jess  amd64         Oracle VM VirtualBox      
ii  base-files      8+deb8u7                   i386          Debian base system miscellaneous files

#> cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

#> cat /etc/debian_version
8.7
```

---

Note: I can not install a 64bit Debian. (see other question about this [install 64 bit Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297920/install-64-bit-debian) for more detail)

Answer (score 1):

You could cross-grade your toolchain (`build-essential` and its dependencies) to `amd64` along with the other packages being removed, but before you embark on that, it turns out `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` won't work with your setup anyway because it attempts to download the file corresponding to your main architecture (the result of `dpkg --print-architecture`).

So I would recommend filing a bug against the package, asking for support of 64-bit Chromium on a 32-bit system; this would require some fixes to `update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree` and a dependency on `binutils:any` (untested though, and I don't know if that would work in Debian 8).

Alternatively, you could download the [source](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/contrib/p/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/pepperflashplugin-nonfree_1.8.3+nmu1.tar.xz), extract the update script from there and force it to run for `amd64` (look for `arch=""` in the script, set that to `x86_64` instead and remove the following `case`).